# WPF DataBinding : Object does not contain what I entered in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I am new in WPF and i wanted to test `DataBinding`, so I wrote the code below:

```
<Window x:Class="testdatabindingcustomobject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="masterGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Montant:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding Path=Montant}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And c# code behind is:

```
namespace testdatabindingcustomobject
{

public class DataBindingTest : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    double montant;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public double Montant
    {
        get 
        {return montant;}
        set
        {
            montant = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Montant");            
        }
    }

    public  DataBindingTest()
    {
        Montant = 0.000;
    }

public void OnPropertyChanged(string mm)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(mm));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public DataBindingTest myObject;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txt.KeyDown += txt_KeyDownHandler;
        myObject = new DataBindingTest();
    }

    public void txt_KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            MessageBox.Show(myObject.Montant.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

For example when i enter 1500 in `TextBox` and type return key The `MessageBox` does not reflect the entered value in text.

Why does my text box not display the value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DataContext` on your window to get the binding work for you -

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txt.KeyDown += txt_KeyDownHandler;
    myObject = new DataBindingTest();
    DataContext = myObject;
}
```

Refer to this link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) for binding overview.

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting the DataContext like RV1987 wrote, you would also need to set the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged, because you won't lose focus which would normally update the source.

```
Text="{Binding Path=Montant, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the DataContext of your MainWindow or the masterGrid to myObject